# Jenkins: password reset?

Tags: jenkins

Plenty of guides to be found but its not working for me, the most basic solution is to set `useSecurity` to false and restart jenkins and thats it.

Well ok, then what? I can't change my password:

/user/[name]/configure says:

**Credentials**

"Credentials are only available to the user they belong to"

The key provided for logging in as admin also doesnt work anymore, since i created the first user.

Comment: wich jenkins version ?

Comment: @Inforedaster 2.19.4, plain install setup through docker

Comment: An Admin account is created when Jenkins is set up first time which still should be available. The credentials can be found (debian/ubuntu) at `/var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword` Is this file present, if so can you login with password?

Comment: any solution to this?